# control structures While loop in python taking input from user using a counter

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need help with a while loop. I cannot seem to format the code correctly in this block, so i'm writing below.

A user needs to enter a name with only a certain name triggering the loop.
Need to print out number of tries it took user before inputting correct name.

I created a user "Joe". If user is Joe the code will run:

```
counter = 0
user = "Joe"
while name != user: 
     counter += 1
While name == user
continue
```

The program must count how many times it took before the name Joe is inputted.

Comment: your pseudo code seems correct, but the 2 last lines makes no sense

Comment: You never update name or user, so you're in a never ending loop. Please create an [mcve] and explain what issue you're having

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
user = "Joe"
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
while name != user:
    name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
    counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

It should be stop condition

```
if name == user:
   print(counter) 
   //Do something here
   break
```

inside while loop for better flow control.

Comment: The stop condition is already embodied in the `while`, why use another `if` inside the loop?

Comment: My bad, I want to say that he should move the stop condition inside the while loop, in case of further flow control.